# How do I prove that -5 is the limit of the given function using a delta epsilon proof?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm trying to find a $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$ that will allow me to prove that

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{3x^{2} + x + 1}{2x^{2} + x - 4} =-5$$

in a delta-epsilon proof.

Since I would like to show that

$$\left | \frac{3x^{2} + x + 1}{2x^{2} + x - 4} + 5 \right | < \epsilon $$

I have done the following scratch work:

$$\left | \frac{3x^{2}+x + 1 + 5(2x^{2} + x -4)}{2x^{2} + x -4} \right |=\left | \frac{13x^{2} + 6x -19}{2x^{2} + x -4} \right| = \left | \frac{(x-1)(13x+19)}{2x^{2} + x -4} \right | < \epsilon$$

If we assume that $\delta < 1$, then $\left | x - 1 \right | < 1$ implies that $(x-1)(13x + 19) < 45(x-1)$. However, I'm not sure how to bound the denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator has a root at about $x = 1.186$. You would want to stay away from that point, so assuming $\delta < 1$ is actually not strict enough. I suggest you use something like $\delta < 0.1$ or similar. For $x\in (0.9, 1.1)$, we have $|2x^2 + x - 4| > 0.48$, which allows you to continue with your proof.

Comment: I made a typo. I apologize.

Comment: @Skm My point remains unaffected.